# what does the phrase ''such as'' mean?

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases, relative-adverbs

I am confused about the phrase ''such as'' in the following sentence.

in second part the pronoun ''it'' make me comfused and the ''it'' seems to refer the phrase ''the genuine teaching of the Buddha", so I'm difficult to take the phrase ''such as'' as ''the genuine teaching of the Buddha"
how should I understand the phrase?

please help me with your simple explanation.

''I shall give a short exposition of the essence of the genuine teaching of the
Buddha, such as we still find it in the Buddhist scriptures handed down to us in
the Pali language.''

page. 1

''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by
Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: such as = for example

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's one definition, not the one being used here.

Comment: I don't think "such as we find **it**" is correct here.  It would sound more fluent if it were just "such as we find in in the Buddhist scriptures..."

Comment: yes. the word 'it' makes difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Such as" has two main uses, as defined in the dictionary:

1. *used to introduce an example or series of examples*
2. *of the specified kind*

In your example, it is the latter. The subject specified in the first clause is "*the genuine teaching of the Buddha*". Of course, the Buddha died over 2500 years ago, so he's not around to tell us what his 'genuine teaching' is, and the writer is adding that this is the teaching as specified in the Buddhist scriptures.

Comment: yes. agreed, but in second part the pronoun ''it'' make me comfused and the ''it'' seems to refer the specified subject  ''the genuine teaching of the Buddha", so I'm difficult to take the phrase ''such as'' as ''the genuine teaching of the Buddha"  Thanks so much...